# Simplification of Levi-Civita Symbol

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, tensors, fluid-dynamics

I need to simpify the following:

$\begin{equation*}
 \varepsilon_{ijk}\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
\end{equation*}$

For the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon$. I tried expanding and grouping terms and I got something that looked like an alternating sum of Hessian matrix terms or something. This is my first exposure to this notation so I'm a bit confused to say the least. I'm supposed to get a simpler expression but I got an expression with six terms. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: one factor is $i\leftrightarrow j$-antisymmetric, the other $i\leftrightarrow j$-symmetric.

Comment: A perfect hint @J.G.

Comment: Work through the case $k=1$.